# code completion for OpenCV in Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, autocomplete, codeblocks

Can you please help me with the following issue?

I am running **Code::Blocks 13.12** on 64-bit Debian Linux. I am new user of this IDE. When I create new **OpenCV** project in Code::Blocks and set proper compiler flags and linker flags, i.e. by putting ...

- *`pkg-config opencv --cflags`* into *Settings > Compiler > Compiler settings tab > Other options tab*
- *`pkg-config opencv --libs`* into *Settings > Compiler > Linker settings tab > Other linker options*
- */usr/include/*, */usr/include/opencv/*, */usr/include/opencv2/* paths into *Settings > Compiler > Search directories tab > Compiler tab*,

compilation of the project is just fine. The only thing that doesn't work is code completion for OpenCV functions.

I have following code in *main.cpp*. When I click right mouse button over the `imread` function and choose *Find declaration of: 'imread'* menu option, an alert  with *Not found: imread* message is raised. But doing same thing on STD's `cerr` works as expected.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main( int argc, char * argv[] ) {

  Mat img = imread( "lena.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR );

  if ( img.empty() ) {
    cerr << "Unable to load the Lena image!" << endl;
    return -1;
  }

  namedWindow( "lena", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
  imshow( "lena", img );

  waitKey( 0 );
  return 0;
}
```

When I choose the *Symbols* tab on the left vertical bar, I can see the *cv* namespace there but it seems empty. There are no subitems and it can not be expanded as the *std* namespace.

Am I doing something wrong? How should I persuade the Code::Blocks to parse also OpenCV's headers? Just restarting/reopenning IDE/project doesn't work. :-)

Thank you very much for your replies.

Comment: I am an experienced CB user and I'm damned if I can get it to work either in 13.12. Another C++ IDE I use on Linux is CodeLite: here, as long as the opencv headers are installed then code-completion, find declaration etc. for the opencv symbols works without do anything additional to the project or compiler config.

Comment: thanks for your confirmation, I'll try CodeLite then ...

Answer (score 0):

Using Code::Blocks 10.05 on Ubuntu 12.04 I am doing this way, you can try this.

Go to **Setting->Compiler and Debugger setting**

- In **Search directories** tab click on **Compiler** sub-tab add OpenCV include path,

  usually, `/usr/local/include`
- Click on **Linker** sub-tab and add opencv bin directory

  Usually  `/usr/local/bin`
- Now go to **Linker setting** tab and on **Other linker option** add link libraries

  like,

  -lopencv_calib3d
  -lopencv_contrib
  -lopencv_core
  -lopencv_features2d
  -lopencv_flann
  -lopencv_highgui
  -lopencv_imgproc
  -lopencv_legacy
  -lopencv_ml
  -lopencv_nonfree
  -lopencv_objdetect
  -lopencv_photo
  -lopencv_stitching
  -lopencv_superres
  -lopencv_ts
  -lopencv_video
  -lopencv_videostab

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work for me. :-( Code::Blocks in version 13.12 probably doesn't parse recursively and correctly all files inside */usr/include/opencv2/* where are placed OpenCV's headers on my system (this path is set in *Search directories* on *Compiler* tab).